# RubyMine feature that records actions

Tags: rubymine

Does RubyMine have a feature that allows me to record a specific function in a webpage, and once I have completed those steps, I can review the ruby code that it used?  I often find it time consuming to identify an element to click (checkbox, buttons, etc).

Comment: Do you want to find the Ruby code that generated e.g. a button on a web page (which has already run by the time you see the button), or do you want to find the Ruby code that runs after to click the button, or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reviewing *all* code that runs during a specific action is I guess possible only with debugger.

If you only wanted to know **which template a given action** (link, button) **is in**, have a look at the **[xray-rails gem](https://github.com/brentd/xray-rails)**. The gem shows you the name of the template right in your browser when you press a magic key. You can also click through the template name to open it in the editor right away.

The template is usually a good starting point for further investigation: in RubyMine you can click on the icon at the top of the left gutter to get to the parent view or the corresponding controller action (see **[gutter icons navigation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/ruby/2016.1/navigating-to-controllers-views-and-actions-using-gutter-icons.html)** help).